# Why double quotes is automatically added to the first cell on CSV Import?

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6

I'm trying to do a CSV(which is generated by a third party) import,in PHP and I've the following fields in the CSV.

> ID, Size1, Size2, OneOrTwo, Min, Max

But on Import I'm getting an array as following

```
Array
(
    [0] => "ID"
    [1] => Size1
    [2] => Size2
    [3] => OneOrTwo
    [4] => Min
    [5] => Max
)
```

I'm getting an output with quote added to the first field name, ie **ID** turns to **"ID"**. If I edit the cell value and re-type the field name and save again, the issue seems to be disappearing. I'm not sure why it happens. It would be of great help if somebody could help me in solving out the problem.

This is the code for import.

```
$currentcsv  = fopen('/data.csv', "r");
    $csvArray  = array();
    while (!feof($currentcsv)) {
        $data = fgetcsv($currentcsv);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $csvArray[] = $data;
        }
    }
echo "<pre>";
die(print_r($csvArray[0]));
```

Comment: try clearing the cache of the browser

Comment: Could you please tell me why you suspect cache could be the issue?

Comment: I had the same problem, i mean i was changing the column type of the cell and the value was the same. After i clear the cache it was ok

Comment: How do you import the CSV file? Please show some code and also the first few lines of the CSV file.

Comment: @Quagaar I've added the code. Please have a look at it and let me know if you need anything else. I definitely hope you'll be able to find out what is the cause now.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi I tried clearing the cache. Still I have that issue, even for the first time when I do an import.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem using your code. Are you absolutely sure the quotes aren't contained in the original CSV? How do you edit the CSV file? Text editor or Excel/Calc or something? Could you do a `file data.csv` on the command line and show the output?

Comment: @Quagaar Yes. I'm sure that quotes aren't contained in the original CSV. I just did a normal edit using the LibreOffice Calc. I tried the filedata.csv as you suggested using the command line, but it is showing without quotes in the terminal.

Comment: You can't be sure how the data really looks using Calc. Open the file with a normal text editor (e.g. gedit) and take a look at the data.

Comment: @Quagaar So will it look different in an editor? If so isn't supposed to show up in the terminal?